# Did any of the sahaba - beside the Prophet Muhammad himself - give fatwa? (Shi'a view)

Tags: prophet-muhammad, history, shiism, fatwa, sahaba

During the life time of the Prophet () did anybody of the sahabah give fatwa according to Shi'a sources?

If so who was/were this/these sahabi/sahabah?

And under what circumstances did he/they give fatwa? (For example was the prophet () present (in the same location or at least area, so that the asker might have the possibility to ask him instead of anybody else).

Or otherwise said was giving fatwa only in the hand of the prophet and none was allowed to give a fatwa except with his permission?

---

Just as an info sunni sources count up to eight sahabah according to imam as-Suyuti (see for example in [this thread](http://m-noor.com/showthread.php?p=28641) -in Arabic) who counted them in a short poem:
وقد كان في عصر النبي جماعة * * * يقومون بالإفتاء قومة قانت
فأربعة أهل الخلافة معهم * * * معاذٌ أبيٌّ وابنُ عوف ابنُ ثابت

Answer (score 1):

The Shiites set conditions for someone to have the right to give a fatwa. For example, he must be born lawful and know the Qur'an and the Sunnah of the Prophet. The Mufti must also be knowledgeable about the ways of obtaining the Shari'ah rulings and how to deduce the rulings from them, as well as all the sciences that play a role in obtaining the rulings, and be able to explain the reasoning and principles of the rulings.

I have not seen as much as my own studies that the Shiites refer to the fatwa of one of the companions during the time of the Prophet's resurrection. Because as long as the person of the Prophet and the infallibles were alive, there was no reason to care about the fatwa of another person. There is an example that says that tayammum is not permissible on the soil as long as there is water for ablution.
The words quoted from the companions are not valid if they are not in the opinion and words of the Prophet.

https://fa.wikishia.net/view/%D9%81%D8%AA%D9%88%D8%A7#%D9%88%DB%8C%DA%98%DA%AF%DB%8C%E2%80%8C%D9%87%D8%A7%DB%8C_%D9%85%D9%81%D8%AA%DB%8C

https://makarem.ir/maaref/fa/category/articles/29946/%d8%b9%d8%af%d8%a7%d9%84%d8%aa-%d8%b5%d8%ad%d8%a7%d8%a8%d9%87